# Going to a job Interview When you accept another offer

Tags: interviewing, ethics

Is it unethical to go to a job interview if you accepted another offer just so that you can travel and get free food/hotel?

Comment: Turn this around. Imagine if the company had already hired someone else, but they asked you to an interview, with no intention of hiring you, because they wanted to fly you out to spend a whole day with them so they could pick your brain.

Comment: ...and they expected you to buy them lunch

Comment: Is this a serious question?

Comment: @Fattie a Motel six, next to an adult bookstore.

Comment: DONE - it's worth the moral risk

Answer (score 11):

> Is it unethical to go to a job interview if you accepted another offer just so that you can travel and get free food/hotel?

If you only reasons are to get free food and hotel then *yes* it would be unethical.

Not only it is unethical, but it's also unprofessional, as you are *wasting these people's time* by going to an interview you never had the intentions of taking their offer, if given.

Answer (score 7):

Yes.  You are falsely presenting yourself as at least a potential new hire, and you're consuming company resources (their time and energy, plus plane tickets, hotel, and restaurant bills).  That's at least at the "sleazy marketing tactics" level of unethical, and arguably worse.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is unethical, unethical, and worthy of ridicule and scorn.

While not technically fraud, it is certainly it amounts to theft by deception, even though you likely would never be charged for it.

Furthermore, to do demonstrate a distinct lack of character and trustworthiness which would follow for a very long time it word ever got out.  It always does.

What is it that would make you think that doing such a thing could be anything but unethical?

You are not only stealing the cost of food, shelter, and travel but also stealing the time of all the hours that people would be spending preparing for the interview.  This is very much unethical and borderline criminal.